# Can't push my code to heroku master

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, github, sqlite

I tried to push my application to heroku but got some errors.

Please help
many thanks

github link:
https://github.com/zombie7158/testapp

system info:
ruby 1.9.3p448 (2013-06-27 revision 41675) [x86_64-darwin12.4.1]

Rails 4.0.0

Running `ruby -v` attached to terminal... up, run.9339

ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [x86_64-linux]

error info:

```
 Counting objects: 83, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressin**strong text**g objects: 100% (72/72), done.
Writing objects: 100% (83/83), 16.26 KiB, done.
Total 83 (delta 16), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Ruby/Rails app detected
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-1.9.3
-----> Installing dependencies using Bundler version 1.3.2
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin --deployment
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
       Installing rake (10.1.0)
       Installing i18n (0.6.5)
       Installing minitest (4.7.5)
       Installing multi_json (1.7.9)
       Installing atomic (1.1.13)
       Installing thread_safe (0.1.2)
       Installing tzinfo (0.3.37)
       Installing activesupport (4.0.0)
       Installing builder (3.1.4)
       Installing erubis (2.7.0)
       Installing rack (1.5.2)
       Installing rack-test (0.6.2)
       Installing actionpack (4.0.0)
       Installing mime-types (1.25)
       Installing polyglot (0.3.3)
       Installing treetop (1.4.15)
       Installing mail (2.5.4)
       Installing actionmailer (4.0.0)
       Installing activemodel (4.0.0)
       Installing activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3)
       Installing arel (4.0.0)
       Installing activerecord (4.0.0)
       Installing coffee-script-source (1.6.3)
       Installing execjs (2.0.1)
       Installing coffee-script (2.2.0)
       Installing thor (0.18.1)
       Installing railties (4.0.0)
       Installing coffee-rails (4.0.0)
       Installing hike (1.2.3)
       Installing jbuilder (1.5.1)
       Installing jquery-rails (3.0.4)
       Installing json (1.8.0)
       Installing pg (0.16.0)
       Using bundler (1.3.2)
       Installing tilt (1.4.1)
       Installing sprockets (2.10.0)
       Installing sprockets-rails (2.0.0)
       Installing rails (4.0.0)
       Installing rdoc (3.12.2)
       Installing sass (3.2.10)
       Installing sass-rails (4.0.0)
       Installing sdoc (0.3.20)
       Installing sqlite3 (1.3.8)
       **Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
       /tmp/build_1xda9qa93kq4/vendor/ruby-1.9.3/bin/ruby extconf.rb**
       checking for sqlite3.h... no
       sqlite3.h is missing. Try 'port install sqlite3 +universal'
       or 'yum install sqlite-devel' and check your shared library search path (the
       location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
       *** extconf.rb failed ***
       Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
       necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
       details.  You may need configuration options.
       Provided configuration options:
       --with-opt-dir
       --without-opt-dir
       --with-opt-include
       --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
       --with-opt-lib
       --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
       --with-make-prog
       --without-make-prog
       --srcdir=.
       --curdir
       --ruby=/tmp/build_1xda9qa93kq4/vendor/ruby-1.9.3/bin/ruby
       --with-sqlite3-dir
       --without-sqlite3-dir
       --with-sqlite3-include
       --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
       --with-sqlite3-lib
       --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/lib
       --enable-local
       --disable-local
       Gem files will remain installed in /tmp/build_1xda9qa93kq4/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.8 for inspection.
       Results logged to /tmp/build_1xda9qa93kq4/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.8/ext/sqlite3/gem_make.out
       An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.8), and Bundler cannot continue.
       Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.8'` succeeds before bundling.
       Bundler Output: Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
       Installing rake (10.1.0)
       Installing i18n (0.6.5)
       Installing minitest (4.7.5)
       Installing multi_json (1.7.9)
       Installing atomic (1.1.13)
       Installing thread_safe (0.1.2)
       Installing tzinfo (0.3.37)
       Installing activesupport (4.0.0)
       Installing builder (3.1.4)
       Installing erubis (2.7.0)
       Installing rack (1.5.2)
       Installing rack-test (0.6.2)
       Installing actionpack (4.0.0)
       Installing mime-types (1.25)
       Installing polyglot (0.3.3)
       Installing treetop (1.4.15)
       Installing mail (2.5.4)
       Installing actionmailer (4.0.0)
       Installing activemodel (4.0.0)
       Installing activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3)
       Installing arel (4.0.0)
       Installing activerecord (4.0.0)
       Installing coffee-script-source (1.6.3)
       Installing execjs (2.0.1)
       Installing coffee-script (2.2.0)
       Installing thor (0.18.1)
       Installing railties (4.0.0)
       Installing coffee-rails (4.0.0)
       Installing hike (1.2.3)
       Installing jbuilder (1.5.1)
       Installing jquery-rails (3.0.4)
       Installing json (1.8.0)
       Installing pg (0.16.0)
       Using bundler (1.3.2)
       Installing tilt (1.4.1)
       Installing sprockets (2.10.0)
       Installing sprockets-rails (2.0.0)
       Installing rails (4.0.0)
       Installing rdoc (3.12.2)
       Installing sass (3.2.10)
       Installing sass-rails (4.0.0)
       Installing sdoc (0.3.20)
       Installing sqlite3 (1.3.8)
       **Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

       /tmp/build_1xda9qa93kq4/vendor/ruby-1.9.3/bin/ruby extconf.rb**
       checking for sqlite3.h... no
       sqlite3.h is missing. Try 'port install sqlite3 +universal'
       or 'yum install sqlite-devel' and check your shared library search path (the
       location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
       *** extconf.rb failed ***
       Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
       necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
       details.  You may need configuration options.

       Provided configuration options:
       --with-opt-dir
       --without-opt-dir
       --with-opt-include
       --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
       --with-opt-lib
       --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
       --with-make-prog
       --without-make-prog
       --srcdir=.
       --curdir
       --ruby=/tmp/build_1xda9qa93kq4/vendor/ruby-1.9.3/bin/ruby
       --with-sqlite3-dir
       --without-sqlite3-dir
       --with-sqlite3-include
       --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
       --with-sqlite3-lib
       --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/lib
       --enable-local
       --disable-local


       Gem files will remain installed in /tmp/build_1xda9qa93kq4/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.8 for inspection.
       Results logged to /tmp/build_1xda9qa93kq4/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.8/ext/sqlite3/gem_make.out
       An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.8), and Bundler cannot continue.
       Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.8'` succeeds before bundling.
 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !     
 !     Detected sqlite3 gem which is not supported on Heroku.
 !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3
 !

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby/Rails app

To git@heroku.com:ancient-savannah-7479.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:ancient-savannah-7479.git'
```

Comment: Can you post your gemfile?

Comment: Can you try `bundle install` prior to pushing your code to Heroku?

Comment: gemfile is in my github link: https://github.com/zombie7158/testapp
I've tried bundle install, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

just delete it

```
group :develppment, :test do
    gem 'sqlite3'
end
```

and add

```
gem 'pg'
```

to you Gemfile and run `bundle` in project dir

Heroku works with postgres

Comment: `gem 'sqlite3'` will only be on dev and test environment. You can use sqlite for dev/test and use `pg` for prod. I doubt that this is the answer.

Comment: from the log shows that bundler attempts to sqlite3. it seems that the problem in this

Comment: Thanks Monk_Code, I add your code and delete gem 'pg' in my gemfile but it still doesn't work.
Is it possible my heroku running on wrong ver.?
I am using ruby "1.9.3" but heroku shows "1.9.2p290"
I type this in my terminal:
$ heroku run 'ruby -v'

result:
Running `ruby -v` attached to terminal... up, run.4263
ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [x86_64-linux]

Comment: I wrote the wrong look at the corrected answer. Your actions are the same?

Comment: I did 2 things, I am not sure which step solved this issue.

1. add `ruby '2.0.0'` in my gemfile.

2. `bundle install --without production` type this in terminal to bundle install

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved but I don't know why? there is my step.

1. add `ruby '2.0.0'` in my gemfile.
2. `bundle install --without production`

Then I check heroku ruby ver. by `run 'ruby -v'`

it shows:

Running `ruby -v` attached to terminal... up, run.4896

ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [x86_64-linux]

It was showed as below before:

ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [x86_64-linux]

Could someone tell me why?