# Can't push to Heroku bc sqlite and original answer does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, heroku

Here's the original answer, which is not working:
[Can't push my code to heroku master](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18671041/cant-push-my-code-to-heroku-master)
(TLDR = Heroku push fails complaining that sqlite didn't install bc Heroku is incompatible with sqlite.)

None of the fixes given for the answer solve the problem (or even change the error):

- Specified pg gem for production? Check
- Ran bundle install? Check
- Committed my changes (and called git status to make sure)? Check
- Updated database.yml and repeated the bundle and commit steps? Check
- Update Gemfile.lock to match the other project with a sqlite/pg mix (that is pushing to Heroku just fine)? Check

I have the same error message as the original poster. There are several duplicates on SO, but so far no new useful information.

I'm at a loss. What am I missing?

I did a push of my repo if anyone wants to look at that: https://github.com/sidhene/mytwetter

specs in case it matters:
ruby -v = ruby 2.0.0p576
rails -v  = Rails 4.0.0
OSX

Comment: Um, have you pushed your most recent code to Github?  Because I'm looking at your Gemfile, and you don't have a pg gem (like you think you do), and your sqlite3 gem isn't nested under a development group

Comment: Your answer is in your question. "Heroku push fails complaining that sqlite didn't install bc Heroku is incompatible with sqlite." which means you need to use postgress instead.

Comment: @JTG - did you scroll all the way down to my 'production do' section?

Comment: @SnareChops - I have pg in 'production do'

Comment: In your github repo that you linked there is no `production do` in your Gemfile: https://github.com/sidhene/mytwetter/blob/master/Gemfile

Comment: @alightholder, This the link to your Gemfile (https://github.com/sidhene/mytwetter/blob/master/Gemfile) that is on Github, and you don't have a `production do` in your Gemfile.  Nor a pg gem, nor are you specifying sqlite3 in a development env.  So obviously, the changes have not been committed and/or pushed to the github repo.

Answer (score 0):

Heroku does not support sqlite databases very readily. This is highly *dis*-recommended and will cause you many problems (like this one) trying to do so. Use Postgress for you database instead.

Also your gemfile does not have postgress identified. You need:

Gemfile:

```
gem 'pg'
```

and database.yml:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: <your-database-name>
  pool: 5
  username: <your-database-username>
  password: <your-database-password>
```

**Update:**

If you are trying to use a combination of Sqlite and Postgress then add postgress as the database for your production and leave sqlite as your development database like so:

```
development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: <your-database-name>
  pool: 5
  username: <your-database-username>
  password: <your-database-password>
```

You will still need the `pg` gem in your Gemfile. And you will need to add sqlite to your Gemfile under development like so:

```
group :development, :test do
  # Add Sqlite
  gem 'sqlite3'
  # Use RSpec for testing: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 2.0'
  # Use Factory Girl for Active Record sample instance object creation: https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  # Use FFaker for random seed generation: https://github.com/EmmanuelOga/ffaker
  gem 'ffaker'
  # Use Shoulda Matchers for validation and association testing: https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers
  gem 'shoulda-matchers'
end
```

This will use Sqlite on your Mac for development, then postgres in heroku.

Comment: As mentioned above, I do have the pg gem.

Comment: lines 48-59 in Gemfile alredy look like pretty much like this. why is it not working?

Answer (score 0):

Solved! Thanks for looking at my commit. I had changed to another directory due to git issues and didn't realize I was still editing the old files. This explains why none of the pg gem adjustments I had made in the new directory were taking effect :O

Basically same answer as the guy who turned out to be pushing from the wrong branch, only in my case it was the directory (I only have one branch).

Answer (score 0):

I actually had a Git issue! Make sure whenever you are pushing to Heroku, you are on the **"Master"** Branch!